# no method named `json` found for opaque type `impl std::future::Future`

Tags: rust

I want to use reqwest to write a rest client, follow the official document https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest and add dependencies like this in toml:

```
reqwest = {version = "0.11.4", feature = ["blocking", "json"]}
```

and this is my code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn get_user_info(id: i64) -> &'static str {
    let resp = reqwest::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
        .json::<HashMap<String, String>>();
    println!("{:#?}", resp);
    return "ok";
}
```

when I compile this code, shows error like this:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `json` found for opaque type `impl std::future::Future` in the current scope
 --> src/common/net/rest_client.rs:5:10
  |
5 |         .json::<HashMap<String, String>>();
  |          ^^^^ method not found in `impl std::future::Future`
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [asynchronous version](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.5/reqwest/#making-a-get-request) of the [GET API](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.5/src/reqwest/lib.rs.html#262). If you want to use the `blocking` one, Use [*`reqwest::blocking::get`*](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.5/reqwest/blocking/index.html#making-a-get-request) instead.
Since you enabled the [*blocking* feature in Cargo.toml](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest#blocking-client), I am assuming that you intended to use the blocking API.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn get_info() -> &'static str {
    let resp = reqwest::blocking::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
        .unwrap()
        .json::<HashMap<String, String>>()
        .unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", resp);
    return "ok";
}
```

If you still want to use async API, you have to [`await` the result before deserializing the response body](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest#example).